# QLineEdit placeholder text not working in Qt 4.6.3

Tags: qt, qt4, placeholder, qlineedit

I am using Qt 4.6.3, and tried to set some [**placeholder text**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) on a QLineEdit. But these methods didn't work:

- using Qt designer (uic)
- through code `ui->lineedit.setPlaceholderText("phtext")`
- `setProperty("placeholderText","phtext")`

The error is that `setPlaceholderText` is not a member of the QLineEdit class.

Is this a [bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-17906?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) and\or is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [placeholderText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) property was introduced in Qt 4.7 (see documentation), so it doesn't exist in Qt 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

While the placeholderText property [exists in Qt 4.6.3](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/v4.6.3/src/gui/widgets/qlineedit.h#line87), it's only enabled for Maemo5 builds:

```
// ### Qt 4.7: remove this #if guard
#if (QT_VERSION >= 0x407000) || defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString placeholderText READ placeholderText WRITE setPlaceholderText)
#endif
```

It seems like you're somehow mixing Qt platforms.